# One folder of assets 404 error on heroku Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

All of the stylesheet subfolders on my Rails 4 app are working in Heroku except one.  The one that doesn't work works FINE in development, but when I deploy it, it doesn't work. It shows a 404 error and loads everything except the scss.  I have 2 different namespaces in addition to the root,  "blog" and "admin".  It's the "admin" subfolder that doesn't work, but it's structured the same as the "blog" subfolder and the "theme1" subfolder of the main site...which both serve the assets fine.

I've tried all the usual asset debugging for asset pipeline (serve_static_files, clean assets, precompile) and it doesn't make a difference because MOST of my assets are working, just not this one folder.

Here is my file structure:
stylesheets

```
├── admin_manifest.scss # this is precompiled
├── _admin
|   ├── css
         ├── "10 stylesheets"
|   └── admin.scss #@imports of the 10 stylsheets & fonts 
├── application.scss # this is precompiled and includes the theme1_manifest.scss as well as plugins, jquery, etc
├── blog_manifest.scss # this is precompiled
├── _blog
|   ├── shortcodes.scss
|   └── theme_style.scss
├── theme1_manifest.scss # this is precompiled
├── _theme1
|   ├── shortcodes.scss
|   └── theme_style.scss
```

Again, the blog and theme1 subfolders work perfectly, and the admin subfolder works in development,  I just can't figure out why it doesn't work in production.

Comment: Warning: I probably can't help, but there is one question I'd ask and that is: can you please unpack the phrase "it doesn't work" - what do you observe happening (or not) and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Ah,  404 error.  I put it in the title, I'll put it in the text.   It just can't find those specific assets and when I inspect, it's a  404.

Comment: try run: heroku config:set RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true

Comment: Can you show the content for file that is loading/importing the _admin css folder? Make sure that the filename in the server is exactly the same as local (the server is case sensitive, locally you don´t see the problem). Also sometimes if you changed the letter cases github don´t get those changes.

Comment: @Bandi that is already the setting in the config file,  is there a reason to set it that way via the heroku toolbelt?

Comment: @Bandi as it was already set that way & most assets were working, that doesn't help

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere does your `admin_manifest.scss` file import the admin subfolder (`@import 'admin'`)? 

Also does your `assets.rb` include your 3 css manifests (`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin_manifest.css blog_manifest.css theme1_manifest.css)`)?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but check that the access permissions on the local admin folder are exactly the same as the other folders that work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises in a production environment and works perfectly fine in development environment indicates that the assets are not being complied.

This is an **issue related to the configuration of a Rails app in Heroku**.

One **solution** is to **precompile the assets in development environment and upload the compiled assets to heroku**.

To know more about this, read about **Heroku configuration for a rails app**.

Follow the following steps:

Ensure the following in the file `/config/environments/production.rb` :

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Add the gem `rails_12factor` along with `pg` gem in production

`gem 'rails_12factor'`

Precompile the css files:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Commit and push the css files to heroku:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Precompiled assets"
git push heroku master
```